# Java Quartz cron expression

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Can someone help me to figure out java quartz cron expression to set a job for every weekday from 1st of the month to 11th of the month at 2.30 pm.

I could achieve from 1st to 11th or week days separately but not together.

For all days from 1st to 11th 
`0 30 14 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 1/1 ? *`

For all Week days
`0 30 14 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *`

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
30 14 1-11 * 1-5
```

See https://crontab.guru/#30_14_1-11_*_1-5

It says future executions will be like this:

```
next at 2018-02-13 14:30:00
then at 2018-02-14 14:30:00
then at 2018-02-15 14:30:00
then at 2018-02-16 14:30:00
then at 2018-02-19 14:30:00
```